# Eigenvectors of circulant multiplied by diagonal

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have a circulant matrix, say A, and a diagonal matrix, say B (of the same size). The eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A are known, since it is circulant. Is there anything I can deduce about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the product AB?

Thank you very much in advance. Katie.

Comment: Is this question too general or something? There is a lot of structure in the matrices already, so apart from adding additional detail to the structure of the diagonal matrix I can't think of any other details I can provide. Or perhaps there is simply no general solution?